# Where is the option to "Add Project Data Source"?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have added an SQL data source into my project and I am currently trying to demo an output of the table I have created.

I plan to use a `BindingSource` control to do so.

However, where there is normally an option to `Add Project Data Source`, I found nothing (seen in Figure 1), where there should be the option (seen in Figure 2).

[image: Figure 1]
[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2019, I have tried using .NET 5.0 (current) aswell as Core 3.1 and Core 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I lost the link where MS says it, but if it helps any I had the same and it turned out this support for databinding is not supported in .Net Core (or at least the version I had). You have to create a windows forms project, then this feature becomes visible.